# How to alter a column datatype to contain special characters?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I created a table to contain a column with datatype `varchar(20)`.

I need to insert values like `12:322:13:aa` , `1:22:00:ee:2w` for the column. How can I do that? Is there any data type that accepts such strings?

Answer (score 1):

Your strings contain only ASCII characters, so any character set is able to store them. But if you need a wider character set, you can specify it for a particular field or whole table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (c VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET "utf8");
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES ("12:322:13:aa"), ("1:22:00:ee:2w");

>SELECT * FROM t;
+---------------+
| c             |
+---------------+
| 12:322:13:aa  |
| 1:22:00:ee:2w |
+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```